# Azure AD B2C - approval upon sign up?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I got Azure AD B2C up and running in my ASP.NET Core web app. But I wonder what's the best way to actually approve new users when they sign up? Is there anything built-in?

Now, anyone can click on Sign-Up link and there you go, you provide your data and click a button. And you're in my tenant Azure AD B2C directory! Now, I'd like to have some control over this.

Did I mention every user costs $1/month when you want to customize Azure AD UI??? (as far as I understand it, correct me if I'm wrong). So if someone goes and sign up 1000 users I'll have to pay for it $1000??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**At this time there is not built-in support for user sign up approval workflows.**

You can achieve this by:

1. **Having a [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) to determine whether a user has been "approved" or not**. You would let users sign up by themselves and you would create an experience or flow that queries the [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) for users that haven't been "approved" and then either approve them or delete them.
2. **Building an invitation flow.** When you invite a user, you'd create the user through the [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet). You would then direct your users to the Password Reset policy as their "account verification" flow.

**As for your pricing question, if you customize the UI via the newer unified sign-up/sign-in policies, you'll only pay the [regular Azure AD B2C pricing model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory-b2c/)**: between $0.0011 and $0.00063 per user depending on how many you have.

Customizing the UI in the older sign-up policy is not really available. As a workaround, you can use Azure AD Premium's company branding feature which is the one that costs $1 per user. If this is the route you are pursuing, I'd recommend voting for this ask: [Fully Customizable Sign-In Page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13062033-b2c-fully-customizable-sign-in-page).

Comment: Oh, thank you! Clarification on pricing is VERY important to me!

Comment: The pricing link seems to talk about charge per authentication per month and not charge per user at the time of writing this comment

Comment: Yes, B2C **just** changed it's pricing model.