# Can I restict who can sign up to Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am considering using Azure AD B2C, but I'm not sure it fits my requirements.
I have to ensure only legitimate customers of the company can sign-up.

1. Can I restrict registrations to e-mails of trusted domains?
2. Can I add an additional step to the registration process such as scanning a QR-code on the product?
3. Can I add an extra field for a model number of a product?
4. Are there other ways I can achieve this?

I checked those two questions, but didn't find if I can do this with policies or Azure AD Graph.

[Azure AD B2C - approval upon sign up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663306/azure-ad-b2c-approval-upon-sign-up)

[Azure AD B2C - how to implement custom sign up process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648884/azure-ad-b2c-how-to-implement-custom-sign-up-process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For disparate business requirements like this, `AD B2C` provides `Custom Policies` as a way to achieve goals.

Yes, you can use `Azure AD B2C Custom Policies` to fulfill your scenario and [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples) is a huge library of samples/examples to help you further.

> 2. Can I add an additional step to the registration process such as scanning a QR-code on the product?

- You can add QR-code scanner in your Auth flow for which you can refer to [Azure AD B2C: TOTP multi-factor authentication](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp/readme.md). You can use this sample to implement your own use case.

> 1. Can I restrict registrations to e-mails of trusted domains?
> 2. Can I add an extra field for a model number of a product?
> 3. Are there other ways I can achieve this?

- You can add new/custom input fields on your sign up page and also [add input validations using Validation Technical Profile with policy.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile)
- This is the only approach through which you can achieve all your goals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have looked into your suggestions.
It looks as though we have to validate either a trusted domain or a serial number of a product.
Does Azure allow for an easy more or less automatic way to do this, or will I have to build my own REST API?

Comment: You can also use Validation Technical Profile - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile, pls check updated response.